# BigDecimal rounding mode issue

Tags: java, bigdecimal

I need to get these results using BigDecimal roundingmode.xxx and setScale(2) :

```
(5.789).setScale(2, RoundingMode.xxx) = 5.79

(2.894).setScale(2, RoundingMode.xxx) = 2.89

(2.895).setScale(2, RoundingMode.xxx) = 2.89
```

Where RoundingMode.xxx **has to be same for the three given values**.

Ive tried all combinations but with no success and Microsoft Excel set the three results with success.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/RoundingMode.html#HALF_DOWN

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is when I was multiplying two `BigDecimal` numbers I got a big result. After that I used `setScale(2, HalfDown)` but did not get the desired result.

**The wrong result**

```
"2.89500004313886165618896484375".setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_DOWN);
```

I need 2.89 and the wrong result was 2.90

**Using `.round(new MathContext(2))` I got it :**

```
 "2.89500004313886165618896484375".round(new MathContext(2));
```

The right result is 2.89

Answer (score 4):

You could use [`ROUND_HALF_DOWN`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#ROUND_HALF_DOWN):

> Rounding mode to round towards "nearest neighbor" unless both
>   neighbors are equidistant, in which case round down. Behaves as for
>   ROUND_UP if the discarded fraction is > 0.5; otherwise, behaves as for
>   ROUND_DOWN.

For your input:

```
static void roundTo(BigDecimal input)
{
    BigDecimal output = input.setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_DOWN);
    System.out.println(input + " => " + output);
}

roundTo(new BigDecimal("5.789"));
roundTo(new BigDecimal("2.894"));
roundTo(new BigDecimal("2.895"));
```

This would produce:

```
5.789 => 5.79
2.894 => 2.89
2.895 => 2.89
```

---

EDIT: As per your comments, the following might work for you:

```
BigDecimal output = input.setScale(3, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_DOWN).setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_DOWN);
```

Comment: we have almost the same answer xD

Comment: I dont know what happens but I didnt get it with round_half_down. I have the value : 2.89500004313886165618896484375 and after use setScale(....) the result is 2.90

Comment: @Al2x (1) From the documentation link above, it'd be obvious that a fraction greater than `0.5` would be rounded up.  (2) Please include correct examples in your question.

Comment: BigDecimal retFrete = valorTotal.multiply(new BigDecimal(compPreco.getPc_frete()/100));
   compPreco.setValorRS_frete(retFrete.setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_DOWN)); and getPc_frete = 10.0 and valorTotal is 28.95

Comment: try to resolve with full value please : 2.89500004313886165618896484375  You will get this 2.89500004313886165618896484375 => 2.90

Comment: @Al2x If you replace the `BigDecimal output ...` line in the `EDIT` above in the function, then you'd get `2.89500004313886165618896484375 => 2.89`.

Comment: @Al2x Doesn't that return `5.7900000862777233123779296875 => 5.79`?

Comment: yes. it does but this one does not 2.89500004313886165618896484375 => 2.90

Comment: @Al2x I'm not sure what code you're trying.  As mentioned in an [earlier comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20546053/bigdecimal-rounding-mode-issue/20546232?noredirect=1#comment30727162_20546232), it'd return `2.89500004313886165618896484375 => 2.89`.

Comment: I see know. I have to use .round(new MathContext(2)) this way I get what I want to. thanks for helping me thinking about

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for [RoundingMode.HALF_DOWN](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/RoundingMode.html#HALF_DOWN)

> Rounding mode to round towards "nearest neighbor" unless both
>   neighbors are equidistant, in which case round down. Behaves as for
>   RoundingMode.UP if the discarded fraction is > 0.5; otherwise, behaves
>   as for RoundingMode.DOWN.

Example:

```
public static void main(String args []){

  System.out.println(new BigDecimal("5.789").setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_DOWN));
  System.out.println(new BigDecimal("2.894").setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_DOWN));
  System.out.println(new BigDecimal("2.895").setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_DOWN));

}
```

Output

```
5.79
2.89
2.89
```